# How to add multiple calendars to one folder in outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar, microsoft-outlook-2016

I have the following problem: I want to set up multiple calendars to later sync them over CalDAV (not related here). Each calendar on the server needs its own representation in the local outlook representation, so multiple calendars need to be created.

Long story short: I was not able to create 2 calendars in the same folder. I will now step through my way with some screenshots.

First I create a new folder `Zimbra` to contain all the new calendars to create. I go to the folder view of outlook, click on add and I am presented an image as below. I call the new folder Zimbra and make it contain calendars. After everything is set as in the image, I click on ok.

[image: Dialog add zimbra folder]

A new folder `Zimbra` is generated. All right so far. I now want to add my first calendar to this folder. Thus I right click on it in the folder view, say `New Calendar...` and get again a dialog. After setting as below, I confirm with OK.

[image: Dialog adding first calendar]

This generates a new calendar just as expected. In the following image you see the structure (image from a different dialog but still correct). Note the small calendar symbol in front of the name (in comparision to the folder symbol).

[image: Dialog adding first calendar]

When I go to the calendar view, the calendar `Sekretariat_Zimbra` is present and I can look at it. Of course it is empty at the moment.

Now I wanted to repeat the steps to add another calendar. It did not work as expected. After a bit back and forth, I ended up with the following structure (keep an eye on the icon in front of the name):

[image: After a few tries]

I created the calendars in the following chonological order:

1. Zimbra (the root folder)
2. Sekretariat_Zimbra
3. Bibliothek_Zimbra
4. Christian Wolf
5. Christian Wolf/Chr Wolf
6. Ch Wolf
7. Christian Wolf/Christian Wolf_Hauptkalender
8. Christian Wolf/Christian Wolf Kalender xy

For all calendars with a calendar icon (`Sekretariat_Zimbra` and `Chr Wolf`) everything seems to work as expected. They are visible in the calendar view and can be checked/unchecked there without hassle.

All other "calendars" are invisible in the calendar view (tab). I can open them in the folders view but this is not the intended behaviour.

I have the impression that outlook only allows a single calendar in a folder and converts any additionall calendar in a folder to a folder as well. This would at least explain (together with the chronological order) the selection of "real" calendars and those "half-calendars".

The intended structure would be something like this:

```
Zimbra
  +- Alice' calendar
  +- Bob's calendar
  +- Christian's calendar
  +- Dave's calendar
```

Can anyone explain the behaviour to me?

Can anyone tell me what I need to do in order to get it working?

This behavious can be reproduced on 2 machines with outlook 2016. It looks most like a bug or a limitation of outlook. What is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to tell that I was a bit dumb. I should have thought about restarting. This morgning I saw (after the nightly shut down) that all folders are marked as calendars and visible in the calendar view..... Lesson learned.

Seems like a bug in the calendar detection. Sorry for the strange question.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to follow your steps and test this on my side: Calendar icon displays correctly. Haven’t become a folder icon. Make sure you’ve always selected “Calendar Items”.

[image]

What’s the version on your side? (I tested with Outlook 2016 Pro Plus MSO (16.0.4849.1000)). Install available updates for Office to see if it helps.

If this does not work, [create a new profile](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-an-Outlook-profile-f544c1ba-3352-4b3b-be0b-8d42a540459d) in case some personal settings are corrupted.